# Is there a way to know which user have called a smart contract in Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I am writing my chaincode for `Hyperledger fabric` in `java`.

I need to know **which principal has called a specific smart-contract** and **store data corresponding to that principal**.

Comment: What did you try

Comment: I am trying to put reviews on Hyperledger fabric. Due to some constraints, I have to write the chaincode in java. My setup consists of a single organization and multiple peers. Any peer can post any review, which is String s. My key-value pair is User A: s  i.e. user a posted a string s. I do not want user B to post on behalf of user A, so I need to know that A indeed posted that review. I am trying to create a function that takes a review s, and then figure out which user has sent it, and then pushes A:s.

Answer (score 1):

If each individual user has their own Fabric credentials to be able to call the chaincode, then every transaction has a signature of the submitter.

From inside the chaincode, you would use [getCreator()](https://fabric-chaincode-java.github.io/release-1.4/api/org/hyperledger/fabric/shim/ChaincodeStub.html#getCreator--).